# ' being automatically replaced by ‹› in Sublime Text 4

Tags: sublime-text

While using **Sublime Text 4** with LaTeXtools in a .tex document **(this doesn't occur in an other file format, like a .txt)**, I get, when pressing "'" to have an apostrophe, this "‹›". I assume this is a keybinding, so I search the User-Keybindings but I can't find anything relevant. I think the problem might be here :

```json
    // overlay specifications (Tobias Schmidt)
    // FIXME: the scope for the four following should actually be text.tex.latex.beamer, but for some reason this does not seem to work
    { "keys": ["<"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<${1:+-}>$0"}, 
    "context":  
        [
            {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex - (string.other.math, meta.environment.math)"},
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\\\(?:item|only|textbf|color|onslide|only|uncover|visible|invisible|alt|temporal)$", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    // wrap in <>
    { "keys": ["<"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<${0:$SELECTION}>"}, "context":
        [
            {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    // move over closing >
    { "keys": [">"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
        [   
            {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^>", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    // delete <> pair
    { "keys": ["backspace"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/Default/Delete Left Right.sublime-macro"}, "context":
        [
            {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "<$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^>", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    // autopair quotation marks (`')
    { "keys": ["`"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "`$0'"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["`"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "`${0:$SELECTION}'"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["'"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^'", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
```

I didn't find anything relevant when googling this.

Comment: Sounds like "smart quotes" to me.

Comment: It was indeed Smart quotes. Thanks !